# How to change boolean in fucntion ussing mockito

Tags: java, mockito

So here is my class:

```
public class FileDeleter implements Deleter {

    public void deleteDirectories(List<GroupOfCountries> organizedCountries, String path) {
        List<String> listOfThreeLettersGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GroupOfCountries groupedCountries : organizedCountries) {
            listOfThreeLettersGroups.add(groupedCountries.getName()); //Here it's adding "ABC" and "PQR" to ArrayList because my countries are Albania, Belgium and Portugal.
        }

        for (String directoryToDelete : listOfThreeLettersGroups) { 
            String pathOfGorupDirectory = (path + File.separator + directoryToDelete); //Here it's creating paths to ABC and PQR directories, for example /home/test/ABC
            File tempfile = createFile(pathOfGorupDirectory);
            deleteDirectory(tempfile);
        }
    }

    protected File createFile(String pathOfGorupDirectory) {
        return new File(pathOfGorupDirectory);
    }

    private boolean deleteDirectory(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] children = dir.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDirectory(children[i]);
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

I want to have 100% missed branches. If I comment these lines:

```
if (!success) {
   return false;
}
```

I have 100% missed branches. But somebody have idea what can I do using mockito/junits to change success into false? Because success always returns true so this if will never happend.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
FileDeleter deleter = Mockito.mock(FileDeleter.class);
Mockito.when(deleter.deleteDirectory(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(false);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because deleteDirectory is private :/

Comment: Then you'll need PowerMock.